# How to show report portal launches with classes instead of gradle suite?

Tags: gradle, kotlin, testng, reportportal

I am using report portal with Kotlin and TestNG and gradle as the build tool

`compile group: 'com.epam.reportportal', name: 'agent-java-testng', version: '4.2.0'`

By default, all the tests are grouped under a single Gradle suite and Gradle test with a list of all Before/After setup and teardowns and individual tests. However, testNG grade reports have the flexibility of seeing tests grouped under the classes in which they belong to.

[Report portal screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h413y.png)

Is it possible to customize the report portal to display the tests under the classes they belong to?

### build.gradle

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()

    ...
    maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/epam/reportportal" }
    ...
}


task runTests(type: Test) {
    useTestNG() {
        testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
        useDefaultListeners = false
        listeners << 'com.epam.reportportal.testng.ReportPortalTestNGListener'
        includeGroups System.getProperty('tag', 'NONE')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it is possible, but it depends on your TestNG suite XML, what we did is each test method we warped around  so each one will get it's own parent that includes children of all of his configurations(before and after) the test and the retries. we also built a maven plugin to help us easily customize the TestNG XML, we thinking of open sourcing it so if you want to use it let me know.

Here is a [blog](https://engineering.datorama.com/suiteng-how-we-simplified-testng-xml-creation-by-developing-a-maven-plugin-61f3ca32bb81)

Comment: Yeah, A Github repo or blog post with an example would be super useful.

Comment: @GauravSingh add the blog related to this